# Base64 plugin doesn't work with pdf file on iOS platform

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have a requirement to convert `pdf` file (actually here it has a native path like so `'file:///.../my.pdf'`) to a `base64` string. I can use [Base64](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/) native plugin for Android platform. But it doesn't support iOS. i.e. `Plugin to get base64 encoding of any IMAGE, Base64 can be retrieved for any file for Android, however for iOS images only supported`. So can you tell me another plugin or any method to do this task? i.e. Convert native PDF file path to a `base64` string.

Comment: 10 seconds of googling would give you this answer. ttps://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-base64-joewsh

Comment: I saw that yesterday. That means still searching for a solution. No luck yet. You mentioned plugin only for `images`. I need it for `PDF`. `Plugin to encode image files to base64` @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native [file plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) did the job for me.

```
let base64String = await this.file.readAsDataURL(pdfFilePath, pdfFilename)
```